# Get specific fields on user profile. Facebook SDK PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a FB app for a client succesfully. However, when I fist time load the app, it takes too much time retrieving users' profile in API

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

In order to reduce the loading time in my page, I just wanna to get the specific fields I need. Is it possible, for example, get only 'username' or 'name' fields?

Thank you

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/

Comment: @CBroe Hi how would i get the work and education details of public user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467486/facebook-api-to-get-friends-profile-details

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can.

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name,username');
```

But I'm not sure it is going to be faster.

More fields can be found in the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to read some `documentation`, there is a lot regarding `PHP` and `Facebook`.

To get the `name` you can do the following:

```
$name = $user_profile['name'];
```

To get the `username` will be easy too (*I don't remember exactly what's the `key` for the `username` in that `array`*), but you can `print` all the information from `$user_profile` by doing the following:

```
print_r($user_profile);
```

**or**

```
var_dump($user_profile);
```

Then you can capture what you need doing the same way as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve user id in facebook by:

```
echo $user_profile['id'];
```

You can retrieve name by:

```
echo $user_profile['name'];
```

Retrieve user first name , last name or middle name:

```
echo $user_profile['first_name'];

echo $user_profile['last_name'];

echo $user_profile['middle_name'];
```

Retrieve user location name:

```
echo $user_profile['location']['name'];
```