# Getting Facebook friends profile details

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, profile

I am using facebook4j API. I want to get the profile details of my friends like education ,employement etc. Buit what I get currently is name id and gender only.
Even though I gave all the extended_permissions for my friends like friends_education_history etc as per given in the [url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/)

Still now I am not getting my friends full profile details. How would I achieve this

```
 ResponseList<Friend> friends = facebook.getFriends();
```

Is there any option to get the education and work history of public profile?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the Facebook4j API but here is what I would try. `Friend` implements `User` so you can use the `User` methods on your `Friend` objects.

```
ResponseList<Friend> friends = facebook.getFriends();

for (Friend facebookFriend : facebookFriends) {
    List<Education> educations = facebookFriend.getEducation();
    for (Education e : educations) {
        /* do anything with the Education object */
        System.out.println("School: " + e.toString());
    }

    List<Work> works = facebookFriend.getWork();
    for (Work w : works) {
        /* do anything with the Work object */
        System.out.println("Work: " + w.toString());
    }
}
```

Documentation:

- The [User](http://facebook4j.org/en/javadoc/facebook4j/User.html) object and its methods.
- The [Education](http://facebook4j.org/en/javadoc/facebook4j/User.Education.html) object and its methods.
- The [Work](http://facebook4j.org/en/javadoc/facebook4j/User.Work.html) object and its methods.

Comment: My issue is work and education details are not come from Facebook API result.I tried in FQL query also it does not return the work and education details

Comment: but it only print user id and names..not education details

Comment: @ Stéphane Bruckert but it only print user id and names..not education details

Answer (score 0):

All the facebook API's provide only the **public data** i.e, if the particular user has made his personal information as **PUBLIC**, then only you will be able to extract it.
I created a test account and made all the information public.I was able to extract all the public information except for email and birthday.
In the facebook4j homePage, they claim that the following can be used to extract any user fields:
***`User user = facebook.getUser(userId, new Reading().fields("email"));`***

But i get null values for email.So, I am still working around it.